# XML to JSON object converting string to scientific notation

Tags: java, json, xml, maven

In my case one of the xml tag value is "09031454866678e6". While converting to json object e in the is considered as scientific notation and converting into "9.031454866678E6".

How should I avoid this conversion and ensure that it is parsed as a string and not a number?

In code:

```
JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(resp);
```

where resp is xml string.

it is failing while setting a value

```
listObject.setObjId(rootJObject.getString("abc"));
```

setobject method is as below

```
public void setObjId(String objId) {
    this.objId = objId;
}
```

maven dependencies used in project is

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.json</groupId>
  <artifactId>json</artifactId>
  <version>20180813</version>
</dependency>
```

I am expecting output to be the same as the original value, "09031454866678e6". It should not convert to scientific notification.

Comment: It would be helpful if you added example XML to parse, and the current JSON output. It makes it easier for people to pick up, experiment, and suggest alternatives if you give them what they need to reproduce and see what is currently being produced.

Comment: I would go one step higher from Mads Hansen's suggestion and ask if you have access to the XML schema or DTD associated with your XML file. By any chance, is this XML the result of extracting data from a source like Excel? Lastly, if you have access to the schema, make sure the data type is `xs:decimal` rather than `xs:double` or `xs:float` because the last two allowed for numbers to be saved in scientific notation while `xs:decimal` does not.

Comment: Underscore-java library has a static method U.xmlToJson(xml).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried calling `toJSONObject(java.lang.String string, boolean keepStrings)` with the second argument set to true?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking. thank you so much.